# Trouble with symfony2 installation

Tags: php, symfony, installation

I am trying to install Symfony2. What I am doing is described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html:

1. curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
2. sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

(this sums up composer installation)

1. composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition . '~2.5'

After I have entered all the parameters(last step of installation) i get this error in console(the path I install symfony2 to is - /vagrant/webroot/pavel - on my virtualbox):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found in /vagrant/webroot/pavel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 28
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

So there are two errors: 1 about LoggerInterface and another about cache clear. I don't know if they are related. 
After the installation i go to my localhost/app_dev.php and I get first error again, but now in browser:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found in /vagrant/webroot/pavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Log/LoggerInterface.php on line 25
```

I really need help here, because i want to do every part of symfony2 "right", without relying on any custom actions.

UPDATE(some people asked me to post composer)

I installed via commands i explained higher in this post, so the composer is self-generated, meaning IT WAS NOT CREATED BY ME AND IT SHOULD WORK. But anyway:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["model.php","controllers.php"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add the composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common issue is that the app/cache and app/logs directories must be writable both by the web server and the command line user. On a UNIX system, if your web server user is different from your command line user, you have  to chmod the folders to ensure that permissions will be setup properly.

If still not working with permissions set to 755 or 777 (just for testing in development environment) try this to clear the cache and logs when you see this message in your browswer

sudo rm -rf app/cache/* app/logs/*

Comment: No, that's not the problem. I've cleared cache. Also, what does that got to do with Symfony not finding class?

Comment: If you don't have access to log and cache folder you can't find the class. Try this:

$ sudo chmod +a "www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs

$ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs

Comment: chmod +a fails on unix. i've read about it seems to be mac specific command.

Comment: I've tried every user possible and 777 rights. Nothing works.

Comment: I started thinking about the way I install via composer after trying this and that... What helped me was to use composer installation WITHOUT sudoing in. Just with standard unix user. It helped and now it works. I'm gonna mark this answer as the right, because the root of the problem was explained properly.

Answer (score -1):

It's look like problems with folder permission. Probably Symfony wants to clear cache after instalation. 
(I'm not sure, but this is first thing which I'd check.

Also you can check if composer has the latest version.

Comment: If you'd read steps I took you would see that I installed composer with curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php and it can't be old.